# Boost.Parameter: named template argument in combination with CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, crtp, named-parameters, boost-parameter

**Warning**: longish introduction ahead needed to explain the problem. The Named Template Argument idiom first described in ch 16.1 of Vandevoorde and Josuttis can be conveniently written with the **Boost.Parameter** library

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <typeinfo>
    #include <boost/parameter.hpp>
    #include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

    struct DefaultPolicy1 {};
    struct DefaultPolicy2 {};

    typedef boost::parameter::void_ DefaultSetter;

    BOOST_PARAMETER_TEMPLATE_KEYWORD(Policy1_is)
    BOOST_PARAMETER_TEMPLATE_KEYWORD(Policy2_is)

    typedef boost::parameter::parameters<
            boost::parameter::optional<tag::Policy1_is>,
            boost::parameter::optional<tag::Policy2_is>
    > PolicySelector;

    template
    <
            class PolicySetter1 = DefaultSetter,
            class PolicySetter2 = DefaultSetter
    >
    class BreadSlicer
    {
            typedef typename PolicySelector::bind<
                    PolicySetter1, 
                    PolicySetter2
            >::type Policies;

    public:
            // extract policies:
            typedef typename boost::parameter::value_type<
                    Policies, tag::Policy1_is, DefaultPolicy1
            >::type P1;

            typedef typename boost::parameter::value_type<
                    Policies, tag::Policy2_is, DefaultPolicy2
            >::type P2;
    };
```

The above code allows to override the optional template parameters of `BreadSlicer` in arbritrary order by naming them `Policy1_is` and `Policy2_is`. This makes it very convenient to to policy-based design with many defaulted parameters.

```
int main()
{
        typedef BreadSlicer<> B1;

        // can override any default policy
        typedef BreadSlicer< Policy1_is<int> > B2;
        typedef BreadSlicer< Policy2_is<char> > B3;

        // order of policy-setting is irrelevant
        typedef BreadSlicer< Policy1_is<int>, Policy2_is<char> > B4;
        typedef BreadSlicer< Policy2_is<char>, Policy1_is<int> > B5;

        // similar static asserts work for B1 ... B4     
        BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((std::is_same<B5::P1, int >::value));
        BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((std::is_same<B5::P2, char>::value));

        return 0;
}
```

In order to avoid very subtle ODR violations with policy-based design (for an explanation see this old [post](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2002/04/28906.php) by Alexandrescu), I would like to be able to apply a CRTP pattern on the named template arguments:

```
    int main() 
    {
            // ERROR: this code does NOT compile!
            struct CuriousBreadSlicer
            :
                    BreadSlicer< Policy1_is<CuriousBreadSlicer> >
            {};

            typedef CuriousBreadSlicer B6;

            BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((std::is_same<B6::P1, CuriousBreadSlicer>::value));
            BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((std::is_same<B6::P2, DefaultPolicy2    >::value));

            return 0;
    }
```

However, the Boost.Parameter implementation above fails to compile because some internal static_assert fails with a message like (VC10 SP1)

> 'main::CuriousBreadSlicer' : an undefined class is not allowed as an
>   argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__is_base_of'

**Question**: can this static checking be turned off? Either through a macro or a template trick?

As to possible work-arounds:

1. The above code is functionally equivalent to [this handwritten
   code](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~kettner/courses/lib_design_03/notes/design.html#NamedTemplateArgs). For that code, the CRTP pattern does work. However, it
   requires a lot of boiler-plate code that Boost.Parameter library so conveniently
   automates.
2. I could require the CRTP parameter to always be first in the list of template
   arguments and not wrap it in a  `Policy1_is` class. This solves the
   compile time errors, but it loses the order independence of overriding.

So it seems that I am what golf players call "in between clubs". Which solution would be best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal example with no CRTP:

```
#include <boost/parameter.hpp>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

BOOST_PARAMETER_TEMPLATE_KEYWORD(Policy1_is)
BOOST_PARAMETER_TEMPLATE_KEYWORD(Policy2_is)

typedef boost::parameter::parameters<
           boost::parameter::optional<tag::Policy1_is>,
           boost::parameter::optional<tag::Policy2_is>
        > PolicySelector;


struct foo {};
struct bar {};
struct baz;
typedef typename PolicySelector::bind<foo, baz>::type Policies;
boost::parameter::value_type<Policies, tag::Policy1_is, bar>::type x; // <- !!!
```

So `boost::parameter::value_type` requires the policy selector to be based on complete types, which is not the case for your handwritten classes.

I'm not completely sure why a class would need itself as its own policy. If you need that, perhaps you could wrap an incomplete type in something complete:

```
struct CuriousBreadSlicer : BreadSlicer <
          Policy1_is<CuriousBreadSlicer *> > // <- compiles
```

Or you could use your own `wrap_incomplete_type<>` template, for clarity.

When you use the policy, you can check if it's wrapped, and unwrap it.

Comment: The CRTP is used to avoid ODR coming from type traits. See the post by Alexandrescu I linked in my question. Essentially, the policy class is used for forcing all specialized traits to be visible. Your wrapping idea is nice. Ideally it should be an extra parameter that defaults to `false` which is to be passed to `boost::parameter::value_type<ArgList, Key, Default, Wrapped=false>`

Comment: Named template arguments seem to be a very essential need for effective policy-based programming. How come they haven't made it into the Standard?